# Well-supported Mac mail client that closely approximates Gmail web interface?

Tags: osx, email-client, gmail

- Free is preferable; well-maintained is a must.  Nothing that stopped development in 2013, for example.
- Something directly from Google designed for this would be excellent.
- I'm running 10.11.6 El Capitan.
- I don't care if it *only* works with gmail and no other webmail services; that's all I'm going to use it for.

I prefer the gmail web interface, but *most* of my interaction with email is done offline, so I can't really escape using Mac Mail.  I'd like to change that.

Comment: I'm trying out Thunderbird; we'll see how it goes.